# Create AD User In C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to create an AD using with C# and have been getting this error every time

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: 'The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this

```
private void ccNewHire_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        String Password = passwordLabel.Text;
        String First = newHireFirstName_TextBox.Text;
        String Last = newHireLastName_TextBox.Text;
        String Cnname = newHireFirstName_TextBox.Text + " " + newHireLastName_TextBox.Text;
        String Username = newHireFirstName_TextBox.Text + "." + newHireLastName_TextBox.Text;
        String Ldap = PathtoOURedacted;
    
        DirectoryEntry newUser = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://PathtoOURedacted");
        DirectoryEntry childEntry = newUser.Children.Add("CN=" + Cnname, "user");
        newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = Username;
        newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = First;  // first name
        newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = Last;    // surname = last name
        newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = Cnname;
        newUser.Properties["password"].Value = Password;
        newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 512;

        newUser.CommitChanges();
        
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: Are you an Admin?  Are you running inside VS.  VS you need to right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Yes I'm running VS as an Admin with the needed permissions on the domain

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
DirectoryEntry newUser = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://PathtoOURedacted");
DirectoryEntry childEntry = newUser.Children.Add("CN=" + Cnname, "user");
```

You're calling the variable `newUser`, but you're setting it to the OU. So you end up changing the attributes on the OU, not on the actual new user object. Just rename those variables:

```
DirectoryEntry ou = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://PathtoOURedacted");
DirectoryEntry newUser = ou.Children.Add("CN=" + Cnname, "user");
```

Also, this won't work:

```
newUser.Properties["password"].Value = Password;
```

The password attribute is [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2), but it has to be set in a very specific way, which the documentation describes. In C#, that looks like this:

```
newUser.Properties["unicodePwd"].Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{Password}\"");
```

Comment: This worked like a dream, I ran into an issue trying to use newUser.Properties["unicodePwd"].Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{Password}\""); So I switched to newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { Password }); and it's working

Comment: You do have to have an encrypted connection to be able to set the password, so that may have been the trouble you ran into. Calling [`SetPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-setpassword) tries to establish an encrypted connection for you. The only downside is that you're making two network requests (one to create the user, one to set the password) rather than just one.